Ошибка "use_2to3 is invalid." Linux LMDE 6
(venv) root@LLoad:~# pip install PyBluez
Collecting PyBluez
  Downloading PyBluez-0.23.tar.gz (97 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 97.6/97.6 kB 645.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

на винде идентичная ошибка

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818465/pybluez-error-in-pybluez-setup-command-use-2to3-is-invalid
